# Bootstrap, неккоректное масштабирование

Tags: bootstrap

Создал разметку вида "колонка-1 колонка-2 сайдбар" (две колонки одной ширины+сайдбар):

```html
<div class="col-md-9">
  <div class="col-md-6"></div>
  <div class="col-md-6"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3"></div>
```

Когда начинаю уменьшать масштаб, сайдбар уходит в самый низ и занимает всю доступную ширину, "колонка-2" уходит под "колонку-1", но они не занимают все свободное пространство (освобожденное "колонкой-2" и "сайдбаром"), а прибиваются к левому краю, оставляя освободившееся место пустым.

Что изменить для того чтобы они вставали по центру равномерно заполняя пространство, как например в этом шаблоне: [пример](http://demo.zooka.io/?item=almond)

Answer (score 1):

Приветствую!
Вообще, в TWBS каждый .col-* должен быть прямым потомком какого-нибудь .row
Тогда они ведут себя "правильно".

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-9">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6"></div>
  <div class="col-md-6"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3"></div>
</div>
```

в Вашем случае.

Answer (score 0):

У меня как бы есть "row", но он еще до "col-md-9", я не стал так далеко лезть, думал проблема именно в  "col-md- "...да и в примере, на который я ссылку дал тоже нет еще одгого "row":

```html
<div id="content">
<div class="site-content">
 <div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9">
  <div class="col-md-6"></div>
  <div class="col-md-6"></div>
  </div>
<div class="col-md-3"></div>
   </div>
</div>
 </div>
  </div>
```

Вроди повторил принцип как  в примере, но хоть убей колонки жмутся к левому краю когда сжимаю браузер...